# How to pass dependencies in Laravel Facades?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel Facade named Helper which has constructor dependency injection to an external Repository. But I am unable to pass its dependency through facades service provider.

Here is the code for Helper.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use App\Repositories\PropertyUpload\PropertyUploadRepositoryInterface;

class Helper
{
    /**
     * @var PropertyUploadRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $propertyUploadRepo;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(
        PropertyUploadRepositoryInterface $propertyUploadRepository
    )
    {
        $this->propertyUploadRepo = $propertyUploadRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Get property Cover Photo
     * 
     * @param int $property_id
     * @return string $img_url
     */
    public function getPropertyCoverPhoto($property_id) 
    {
        $property_uploads = $this->propertyUploadRepo->findBy(['property_id' => $property_id, 'status' => 1]);


        return $property_uploads;
    }
}
```

Here is what i do in FacadesServiceProviders.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Repositories\PropertyUpload\PropertyUploadRepository;

class FacadesServiceProviders extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('helper', function(PropertyUploadRepositoryInterface $propertyUploadRepository){
            return new \App\Helpers\Helper($propertyUploadRepository);
        });
    }
}
```

But Now I am getting this error

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
>
> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Providers\FacadesServiceProviders::App\Providers{closure}() must
>   be an instance of App\Providers\PropertyUploadRepositoryInterface,
>   instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application given,

If i removed the constructor dependency, My Helper facades works fine. So there is no error in configuring the facade.

My Question is how to pass constructor dependency in above Laravel Service Provider?

If anybody has previous experience with these situation please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just bind the class itself and let Laravel handle the instantiation, it will use reflection to determine the dependencies.

```
$this->app->bind('helper', \App\Helpers\Helper::class);
```

This, of course, assuming you've bound a concrete class to the interface PropertyUploadRepositoryInterface so Laravel can inject the correct dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally:

You don't need the binding unless you want to have it. Your facade could just access the binding named `App\Helpers\Helper` and it would resolve it with no problem (as long as `App\Helpers\Helper` can be resolved from the container).

```
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return \App\Helpers\Helper::class;
}
```

Then on top of that you don't even need to make a Facade to use a Facade even.
`\Facades\App\Helpers\Helper::randomMethods()` would use the real time facade for that class.